# draw two circles which has intersect each other,from that i need to find that intersect point using c#

Tags: c#, math, geometry

Draw two circles which has intersect each other, from that I need to find that intersect point using c# using directx.  I need to find two points.

Comment: If the circles intersect, there will be two points, not one. If the circles are just touching, then you'll have one point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need DirectX here? This is purely mathematical problem. See [this](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/2circle/):

[image: Intersection Of Two Circles]
<sub>(source: [uwa.edu.au](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/2circle/2circle1.gif))</sub>

Comment: sir i saw that.would u give much solution for this both radius r equal
for both circle

Comment: @ratty: Surely you just plug the same number in for both r0 and r1? Why would it be any harder than that?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with DirectX really, or even C#. It's just geometry. See [this page](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/2circle/) for the appropriate formula and reasoning.

Comment: DirectX does provide vector and matrix types (among many other) and methods to operate on them so perhaps the person setting the 'homework' wanted the 'class' to concentrate on the algorithm rather than the implementation of basic types.